# What is the name of a scale starting on D and containing D, F, G and Ab

Tags: scales

What is the name of a scale starting on D and containing D, F, G and Ab?  Only these four notes are used in the melody.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a scale; I'd call it a [pitch set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(music)), and it wouldn't have its own name. That's not really helpful, though. These pitches could be included in many scales, though. I suspect that the question you really ask is "how can I describe the tonality of this piece." To answer that we'd need to see the musical material itself; it's about more than just which pitches are used.

Comment: Why would it be a scale of only 4 notes? Even pentatonics have 5!

Comment: Also important: just because a note appears in the melody doesn't guarantee it's part of the underlying scale. I could write in D minor and use A flats—I could easily imagine it in a boogie-woogie context in fact. For now I'm voting to close this question as lacking details and clarity, but I encourage you to edit it to add some details or focus the question. You might want to read through [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); note that the obvious question, "So what key is this in anyway," is not covered, though more in-depth theory analysis can be.

Comment: Is this an exam question?

Comment: @AndyBonner the question seems to be asking for the name of a scale that contains the given pitch set (among other criteria), i.e., a scale of which the given pitch set is a subset.  By definition, the answer to that question will be a scale (if one exists).

Answer (score 6):

It sounds most like a subset of a D minor [blues scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blues_scale) (D-F-G-Ab/G#-A-C-D).

Comment: Blues uses b5, jazz uses #4.

Comment: @Tim I've added the A-flat

Answer (score 3):

One such scale is D locrian, but the chance that your melody is in D locrian is pretty small.

Comment: Could also be the octatonic scale in D.